# The provider is disable or unsupported capacitor firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, capacitor

Trying to do a Google Auth using firebase and capacitor-firebase-auth plugin but keep getting this issue. and Google Auth is enabled on my firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if google is really enabled.
If it is then the problem might be in the configuration file. Check if it is properly configured, also if you plugin configuration is on capacitor.config.json it might help to move it to capacitor.config.ts (it worked once for me)